# Mysql stored procedure returning all results

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

The below procedure is returning all select statements even the ones that are putting data into a variable.
My previous experience was with mssql and this is my first procedure in mysql.
I want result of only the final select i.e., `select * from temp_cust_value;`.
Any help to solve this issue will be much appreciated.

```
  BEGIN


    create TEMPORARY TABLE temp_cust_value(id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    customerid int, customername varchar(40), spent decimal(30,3),PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

    insert into temp_cust_value(customerid,customername,spent)
    select t2.customerid,customer_name, sum(price) as Totalcost
    from Transaction t 
    left join 
    (select o.`OName` as customer_name,c.`CustomerID`,c.`CustomerType` from Customer c
    left join Organization o on c.`CustomerID`=o.`CustomerID` where c.`CustomerType`=1
    union all
    select i.`IName` as customer_name,c1.`CustomerID`,c1.`CustomerType` from Customer c1
    left join `Individual` i on i.`CustomerID`=`c1`.`CustomerID` where `c1`.`CustomerType`=0) t2
    on t.customerid=t2.customerid

    Group by t.customerid,customer_name order by sum(price) desc  ;

    #select * from temp_cust_value;





    set @cnt=1;



    select @rowcount := MAX(typeid) from `Type`;
    #select @rowcount;

    /*select @rowcount := MAX(typeid) from `Type` ;
    #set tempquery= 'ALTER TABLE temp_cust_value ADD';
    #select @rowcount;
    set @rowcount=4;*/

        while @cnt<=@rowcount do

        select t.`TypeName` into @typename1 from `Type` t where t.`TypeID`=@cnt and t.`TypeName` is not NULL;
        #select @rowcount;


        /*select @typename1 := t.`TypeName` from `Type` t where t.`TypeID`=cnt and t.`TypeName` is not NULL;*/
        set @sql1 := concat("ALTER TABLE temp_cust_value ADD ",@typename1," int DEFAULT 0;");
        #select @sql1;
        PREPARE stmt3 FROM @sql1;
        EXECUTE stmt3;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;

        set @cnt=@cnt+1;
        end while;

    #select * from temp_cust_value;



    create temporary table gallery_customer_type_money(id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    customerid int, typeid int, money int,PRIMARY KEY (`id`));



    insert into gallery_customer_type_money(customerid, typeid,money)
    select c.`CustomerID`,t2.`TypeID`,sum(p.`price`) from `Customer` c
    inner join `Transaction` t on t.`CustomerID`=c.`CustomerID`
    left join `Piece` p on p.`InvoiceNumber`=t.`InvoiceNumber`
    left join `Type` t2 on t2.`TypeID`=p.`TypeID`
    #where t2.`TypeID` IS NOT NULL
    group by c.`CustomerID`,t2.`TypeID`; 
    #order by c.`CustomerID`,sum(p.`price`) desc ;

    #select * from gallery_customer_type_money;

    set @cnt1 := 1;
    #set @rowcount1=1;
    select @rowcount1 := MAX(id) from `gallery_customer_type_money`;
    #select @rowcount1;
    while @cnt1<=@rowcount1 do

    select @a := customerid, @b := typeid, @c := money from gallery_customer_type_money where id=@cnt1;



    #select @typedesc := t.`TypeName` from `Type` t where t.`TypeID`=@b and t.`TypeName` is not NULL;

     select t.`TypeName` into @typedesc from `Type` t where t.`TypeID`=@b and t.`TypeName` is not NULL;



     set @sql2 := concat("update temp_cust_value set ",@typedesc," =",@c," where customerid=",@a,";");

        #select @sql2;
        PREPARE stmt3 FROM @sql2;
        EXECUTE stmt3;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;


    set @cnt1=@cnt1+1;
    end while;



    select * from temp_cust_value;


    drop table temp_cust_value;
    drop table gallery_customer_type_money;
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

OK. This got solved. I used set or select into to solve this.